# How to concatenate two strings on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, string

How to connect string "Hello" and string "World" to "HelloWorld"? Looks like "+" doesn't work.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"Hello", @"World"];
NSLog(@"%@", string);
```

That should do the trick, although I am sure there is a better way to do this, just out of memory. I also must say this is *untested* so forgive me. Best thing is to find the stringWithFormat documentation for NSString.

Comment: You’re just missing @s on the Hello and World strings, otherwise this should work fine. There is also a message stringByAppendingString in NSString.

Comment: This is exactly what I do, but as zoul said, prefix the strings with @ (ie @"hello")

Comment: Yeah, NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"Hello", @"World"]; is also correct.

Comment: If you plan on releasing the NSString, you should do an alloc and an initWithFormat. NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@", @"Hello", @"World"];

Answer (score 28):

How about:

```
NSString *hello = @"Hello";
NSString *world = @"World";
NSString *helloWorld = [hello stringByAppendingString:world];
```

Answer (score 10):

If you have two literal strings, you can simply code:

```
NSString * myString = @"Hello" @"World";
```

This is a useful technique to break up long literal strings within your code.

However, this will not work with string variables, where you'd want to use stringWithFormat: or stringByAppendingString:, as mentioned in the other responses.

Answer (score 5):

there's always NSMutableString..

```
NSMutableString *myString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Hello"];
[myString appendString: @"World"];
```

Note:

```
NSMutableString *myString = @"Hello"; // won't work, literal strings aren't mutable
```

Comment: You can not create a mutable string by assigning a literal string directly to the variable. You must do `NSMutableString *myString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Hello"];` to create the mutable string.

Answer (score 3):

```
t3.text=[t1.text stringByAppendingString:t2.text];
```

Answer (score 1):

Bill, I like yout simple solution and I'd like to note that you can also eliminate the space between the two NSStrings:

```
NSString * myString = @"Hello"@"World";
```