# Concatenating NSStrings in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How do I concatenate to `NSStrings` together in Objective C?

Comment: Are you asking how to concatenate two strings?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589395/how-to-concatenate-two-strings-on-iphone

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have a mutable string then you can do:

```
NSMutableString* someString = [NSMutableString stringWithString: @"Hello"];
[someString appendString: @", world!"];
```

For example. Be more specific if this is not the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 22):

If the string is not mutable, you will instead want:

```
NSString *firstString = @"FirstString";
NSString *secondString = @"SecondString";
NSString *concatinatedString = [firstString stringByAppendingString:secondString];
// Note that concatinatedString is autoreleased, 
// so if you may want to [concaticatedString retain] it.
```

For completeness, here's the answer for a mutable string:

```
NSMutableString *firstString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"FirstString"];
NSString *secondString = @"SecondString";
[firstString appendString:secondString];
// Note that firstString is autoreleased, 
// so if you may want to [firstString retain] it.
```